# How can I access the token which is saved in the header using angular

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, frontend

I am sending the 'auth-token' which is generated with JWT to the frontend which is built in angular. The backend is built in nodejs. when I try to access the auth-token variable from the frontend it is saying syntax error. How can access this header token in my angular code?

Frontend Request in the component

```
 onSubmit(){
    if(!this.signinForm.valid){
      return;
    }

    const userDetails: SigninAccount = {
      email: this.signinForm.controls.email.value,
      password: this.signinForm.controls.password.value
    }

    this.loginservice.loginUser(userDetails).subscribe(
      data => { console.log(data);
        this.router.navigate(['/'])
      },
      error => { console.log(error.error)}
    )
   

  }
```

Frontend service and the headeroptions

```
  const loginhttpOptions = {
   headers: new HttpHeaders({
     'Content-Type': 'application/json',
   })
  } 

  loginUser(user: SigninAccount): Observable<SigninAccount> {
    const makeReqURL = `${this.apiURL}/login`;
    const loginUser = this.http.post<SignupAccount>(makeReqURL, user, httpOptions)
    return loginUser;
  }
```

Backend response

```
   const userToken = jwt.sign({ _id: user._id }, process.env.TOKEN);
    res.header('auth-token', userToken).send(userToken)
```

Screenshot of the image in the browser and the syntax error message which is given because of the console.log(data).

[image]

the "text" has the JWT token too which is the same as the "auth-token" but don't know how to access it in the code and I don't know what is the syntax error either.

Please help.  Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There must be some syntax issue in backend code that's why you getting the error. Use some linter like EsLint which can help detecting the error.

How to access the authToken?

Here is your new backend code.

don't set token in header instead send as a json.

```js
   const userToken = jwt.sign({ _id: user._id }, process.env.TOKEN);
    res.json({token: userToken});
```

The frontend code is correct you gonna get your `token` in console.

```
this.loginservice.loginUser(userDetails).subscribe(
      data => { 
        console.log(data);
        const token = data.token;
        //Save to localStorage
        localStorage.setItem('token',token);
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
      },
      error => { console.log(error.error)}
```

Comment: JustRaman Thank you very much. I have done this and it nearly worked all i had to do is to add data.toString() to save get the correct value of the token. Thank you you verymuch for your help again.